# Listening for Fingerprint in android using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, fingerprint

Is there a way to get the fingerprint when the device is locked?
can this be achieved using cordova or other hybrid technologies without using native code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get the user's fingerprint data from the device. Fingerprint data is stored in a secure place by Android OS and is not accessible to apps.

However, you can achieve this by prompting the user to use an external fingerprint reader which often comes with its own SDK.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am willing to achieve this from the inbuilt mobile fingerprint reader.
My main concern is whether this can be done while the device is at sleep/locked state.

Comment: @Shoaeb, it's not possible to extract user's fingerprint data from Android OS. What you can however do is, you can get the fingerprint for authentication purposes from your app using Fingerprint API (Introduced in API 23 Marshmellow), for that too, your app must be started by the user. What you are trying to achieve can only be done if your app has critical OS permissions which is not possible for externally installed apps. So, what I can infer is, this is not possible. I hope this solves your query.

Comment: I will look for an alternate way to do this.
Maybe rooting will help.
Thanks for your answers